# Mobile menu icon and carousel not working in wordpress website built with elementor

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, elementor

I'm facing a problem with a Wordpress website built with elementor, the mobile menu icon not and the carousel not working on the browser but when I click "visit site" from the dashboard, it works perfectly (I'm attaching screenshots), also contact form not working. I tried every possible way to troubleshoot like disabling enabling plugins, changing the theme, and also tried to build the menu icons with other plugins but nothing worked.

Please help [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44kx0.png)